# Update MySQL through objective-c

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I'm making a 'post text' app and trying to update my database with name and body field. The obj-c code looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)post:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"%@", name);
    NSLog(@"%@", body); 
    // create string contains url address for php file, the file name is post.php, it receives parameter :name
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/post.php?name=%@&body=%@",name, body];

    // to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    // to receive the returend value
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
}
```

And the php code looks like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['body']) && strlen($_REQUEST['name']) > 0 && strlen($_REQUEST['body']) > 0) {
    //get data
    $title = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];

    mysql_connect("MyServer","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error());

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    //insert data
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($body)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')") or die(mysql_error());

    die("Your text has been posted!");
} 


?>
```

Sometimes it works to post through the app but then it just post (null) as name and null as body. But for the most part it doesn't work at all. It just says in the log:

```
    2012-06-26 16:54:49.893 AppName[12444:707] 
<UITextField: 0x17a390; frame = (63 76; 194 31); text = 'MyName'; 
clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x17a4c0>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a wild guess here but are `name` and `body` pointers to a UITextField object? I'm thinking they might be, based on your log output. If so, you need to use `[name text]` or `name.text` to get the actual NSString value from the text field.

Comment: Also: look up `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` in the NSString class; otherwise your code will fail the first time you try to post anything with an `&` in it.